# Running python with boto2 as an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto

I am using a python script from github to run on AWS lambda.
I realized that the import boto statements are not working while running inside lambda.
Is there way to instruct lambda to load boto2 as well?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Thank you, that just worked!

Answer (score 2):

OK, all I had to do was install boto using "pip install module-name -t /path/to/project-dir" per the docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Then zipped the files needed for lambda and uploaded.