# How to get boto3 authorization on AWS Lambda without uploading a zip file

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

Looking at the boto3 authentication scheme it seems like it uses a configuration file based authentication approach.

This link suggests that to authenticate with Lambda you can simply upload your code (zipped) after installing boto3 locally. [Running python with boto2 as an AWS Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138775/running-python-with-boto2-as-an-aws-lambda-function)

I was hoping there was something simpler I could do from within the aws lambda web interface to log in.

This is the code I'm running which returns "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetFunction operation"

```py
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client('lambda',region_name='us-east-2') 
    response = client.get_function(FunctionName='jims_first_function')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried manually creating the `.aws` directory and associated credentials in the root directory and that failed. Not sure if that was because it wasn't in the `/opt` directory or not.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration

However after a bit more digging I found this link:
[How should I pass my s3 credentials to Python lambda function on AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161761/how-should-i-pass-my-s3-credentials-to-python-lambda-function-on-aws/43162105)

Basically it indicated that I needed to be digging around the permissions tab to modify policies associated with the default role. Clicking on the role brings up the IAM policy management window. In there I clicked on "Attach Policies", selected the `AWSLambda_FullAccess` option, and added it (that might be overkill, not sure). I might have needed to redeploy the code, not sure. After testing everything works.